# How would I repeat TMUX send command x number of times

Tags: tmux, read-eval-print-loop

Sometimes I find myself coding in some repl, writing and debugging some function/logic with a little bit of trial and error, kind of testing some thought process out.

If it's a simple function, I can tap the up arrow until I find the start, hit enter, do the same thing for a few lines until I hit the spot I want to edit.

But if I run a few other commands and play around with a few other things before my mind gets back to the other idea I'd like to play with more, I might find myself hitting up repeatedly, like 25 times, then enter, and repeat, until I'm ready to edit.

I do this because I had a ahha moment and I don't want to have to rethink all that work and forget my ahha.

Since I'm always in tmux, I figured maybe I could find some way of sending keypresses x number of times.

What I found was, I could hit ctrl+b, then `:send Up` to simulate my up arrow key.

Being a heavy vim user, I figured there might be a way I can enter the quantity as well, like I can in Vim.

For example, Ctrl+b `:15 send Up`, or `:send 15 Up`.

No luck.

I've searched for it using different keywords, no luck either.

I feel like I'm missing something simple and easy but am brainfarting it at the moment.

How could I repeat this `send` command x number of times?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

`:run-shell 'for i in $(seq 1 25); do tmux send-keys "#$i" Enter; done'`